# File creation permissions in C

Tags: c, file, file-permissions

I'm creating a file in **C** using the following code:

```
int outfd = open(arg,O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, f_per);
```

`f_per` being the file permission numbers.

Setting `f_per` to `0644`, executing the code and doing an ls -l gives me the (output) file permissions set as `-rw-r--r--` which is expected. However, setting things to 0777 gives permissions as `-rwxrwxr-x` instead of `-rwxrwxrwx`. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: If you're on POSIX: `umask`?

Comment: Cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/how-umask-system-call-is-masking-the-permission

Comment: Ah! I was missing that `unmask`. What does it do anyway? (Not very experienced with C)

Comment: Not `unmask`. `umask`. As in `man umask`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [POSIX page for the `open` call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), under `O_CREAT`:

> ... the access permission bits of the file mode shall be set to the value of the argument following the oflag argument taken as type `mode_t` ***modified as follows: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode creation mask.***

The mode creation mask (or umask) can be considered a subtractive one. For example, if you attempt to create a file with permissions `rwxrwxrwx/0777` when your file mode creation mask is `-------w-/0002`, you'll actually end up with:

```
  rwxrwxrwx
& rwxrwxr-x (complement of -------w-)
  =========
  rwxrwxr-x
```

This appears to be the situation you are encountering.

If you want to actually create a file of the specific permissions, you can temporarily disable the umask by setting it to zero (and restoring it afterwards), something like:

```
mode_t oldmask = umask(0); // needs sys/stat.h
int outfd = open(arg, O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0777);
umask(oldmask);
```